# PHP create a range of sequential rows

Tags: php

How can I modify this code for the second array's values to start with "value 4" and end with "value 6"? Basically the first parameter of range() should be dynamic but I'm not sure if that's possible?

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
    $rows[] = array_map(function($n) {
        return "value " . $n;
        }, range(1, 3));
}
```

`print_r($rows)` should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value 1
            [1] => value 2
            [2] => value 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value 4
            [1] => value 5
            [2] => value 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've restructured your code a little. This is my solution:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
  $rows[] = array_map(function($n) {
    return "value " . ($n+1);
  }, range($i*3, $i*3+2));
};

print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$row=array();
foreach(range(1,2) as $idx)
{
    $row[]=array_map(function($n){return "value $n";},range(($idx-1)*3+1,$idx*3));
}
print_r($row)
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value 1
            [1] => value 2
            [2] => value 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value 4
            [1] => value 5
            [2] => value 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `for` loop is not necessary in your logic, you can directly give it in `range`

```
$rows = array_map(function($n) {
    $n = 3 * $n;
    return array("value " . (1+$n), "value " . (2+$n), "value " . (3+$n), );
  }, range(0, 1) // 0 to max as in for loop
);
```